# Loop thru markers created by google

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am doing what this link shows and that works fine.  I would like to be able to add a tooltip when I hover over a marker and have it say something specific.  I think i can figure out the tooltip part if someone could help me to figure out how to loop thru all the markers that get plotted on the map automatically.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no way to get bound markers, but you can set `suppressMarkers` of `directionsDisplay` option to `true` and draw markers manually

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m79vghtd/)